# Доступ к файлу proc//mem

Tags: c++, linux, c, posix

При прохождении одного из онлайн тестов наткнулся на сложный вопрос. Вопрос формулируется примерно так:

Не удаётся прочитать файл /proc//mem даже из под рута из-за ошибки доступа (permission error). Как решить эту проблему?
Код открывающий этот файл на чтение:

```
int mem_file = open("/proc/12345/mem", O_RDONLY);
```

Варианты ответов:
1. Использовать ptrace

```
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, 12345, NULL, NULL);
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
int mem_file = open("/proc/12345/mem", O_RDONLY);
...
close(mem_file);
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH);
```

2. Послать сигналы SIGSTOP/SIGCONT:

```
Kill(12345, SIGSTOP);
int mem_file = open("/proc/12345/mem", O_RDONLY);
...
close(mem_file);
kill(12345, SIGCONT);
```

3. Проверить атрибуты исполняемого файла и удалить immutable profile.
4. Это не работает из под рута. Нужно проверить пользовательский режим и задать разрешения.

Текст исходников приведён как есть, с сохранением опечаток в оригинале.

После чтения документации и компиляции и запуска кода, я обнаружил, что варианты 1 и 2 оба работают даже без рута. Но видимо какой-то один из них более правильный. Подскажите пожалуйста, какой из этих вариантов лучше подходит для доступа к памяти процесса?

Comment: если читал документацию, то должен понимать, что вариант (2), вообще говоря, не должен работать...

Comment: Почему же тогда файл открывается?

Comment: код в студию — или в нём ошибка, или какой-то частный случай, или что-то не так с окружением...

Comment: `fmemopen()/open_memstream()` ? В линуксе все есть файл. В данном случае файл виртуальный, создаётся ядром. Но, чтение первого байта /proc/pid/mem всегда приводит к ошибке ввода-вывода. Так задумано.

Comment: немного очитался в `man 2 ptrace` — думал, что оттуда следует, что ответ, очевидно — (1). Однако на последующих тестах заметил, что не могу воспроизвести отказ описанный в вопросе... возможно тест устарел? или это вопрос с какой-то подковыркой...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, там оба варианта рабочие, для второго условие запуска из под рута. И в чем смысл вопроса с задания - неясно. Вероятно правильный ответ подразумевает проверку того кода который ТС обозначил точками. И смысл вопроса, что файл надо читать со смещением.

Comment: @NewView, я не получаю EPERM даже при обычном открытии/чтении, как в вопросе теста... тем более от root'а... так что ни один из вариантов (1)-(4) не описывает необходимого условия на мой взгляд... правда что подразумевают под `immutable profile` в (3) — яхз, так что может быть в этом подковырка...

Comment: `immutable profile` - http://xmodulo.com/make-file-immutable-linux.html в принципе это просто управление атрибутами, к /proc/??? отношения не имеет. В понимании ibm этот вопрос: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-lpic1-104-5/

Comment: @NewView, во-первых ни разу не встречал, что бы по отношении к `chattr +i` упоминалось `immutable profile`, а во-вторых, он действительно не имеет отношения к вопросу, так что тут может подразумеваться что-то другое... может какая-то политика SELinux...

Comment: Да сейчас модно придумывать модные названия к обыденным вещам :) от туда же ноги растут и у immutable profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтение первого байта `/proc/pid/mem` всегда приводит к ошибке ввода-вывода. Так задумано. В этом файле надо читать со смещением. Смещение совпадает с реальным смещением в запущенной программе.

Что-бы узнать о смещениях памяти используемых программой нужно читать `/proc/pid/maps`, там указанны используемые регионы памяти.

**Важно**:

1. вы не сможете прочитать mem файл другого работающего процесса, получите ошибку `Нет такого процесса`.
2. если все же есть необходимость читать mem файл другого процесса, то необходимо присоединиться к процессу, используя `ptrace()` вызов. Но все не так просто, и процесс надо останавливать на время чтения.
3. процесс, выполняющийся от имени root, может читать память любого процесса без вызова ptrace, но наблюдаемый процесс должен быть остановлен, иначе все равно получите ошибку.

Есть ещё куча нюансов при работе с виртуальными файлами ядра, рекомендую знакомиться с исходными кодами кернеля если у вас возникают вопросы.

Вот примерный сценарий на `C` чтения mem файла по методу номер 2:

```
sprintf(fname, "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET);
read(fd, buffer, _SC_PAGE_SIZE);
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
```

Посмотрите на [mem_open](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/fs/proc/base.c#L780) и на [check_mem_permission](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/fs/proc/base.c#L194) для понимания как там все устроено.

Comment: Т.о. правильный ответ на вопрос ТС это 2) sigstop/open-read-close/sigcont

Comment: Кстати, чтение должно быть как-то выровнено, или читать можно с любого смещения в странице, отображенной на физическую память (т.е. присутствующей в `/proc/<PID>/maps`)?

Comment: Выравнивание обычно по размеру `_SC_PAGE_SIZE`, от офсета из map файла, главное не убежать за размер :)

Comment: про то что процесс необходимо остановить (и даже то что нужно его трассировать) — устаревшая информация, на современных ядрах (старше 3.0, ориентировочно) происходит только проверка прав доступа на основе [fs]uid/gid...

Comment: @avp, читать можно произвольными объёмами из произвольного места (в рамках адресного пространства разумеется и того что позволяет `read()`)...

Comment: Интересно, про линейку 3.х, пойду почитаю